# Can't link Boost Thread library

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker

I'm trying to compile a dynamic library on Linux (`.so`), written in `C++`.

Since some compatibility issues with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, inside the library code I handle the multithreading by the Boost libraries.

When I compile my library I use the `-lboost_thread` flag.

The compilation ends with no errors, but it seems that the Boost libs aren't linked:

```
ldd myLib.so.1.0 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe81ff000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2e9ad43000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2e9aa47000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2e9a830000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2e9a471000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2e9b348000)
```

Furthermore, when I try to load my library inside an application I get this error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZTIN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseE
```

Can anyone give me some hints?

Please, ask if you need more details.

Thank you.

#

Edit: this is how I build my library

```
CC=g++ -c
CFLAGS=-I./acml530_amd64/ifort64_mp/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/include/linux
LFLAGS=-L./acml530_amd64/ifort64_mp/lib -lacml_mp -lboost_thread 
OUTPUT_DIR=./build/

./svdlibc/las2.o: ./svdlibc/las2.cpp
    $(CC) -c -w -fPIC -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)las2.o $< $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)

./svdlibc/svdlib.o: ./svdlibc/svdlib.cpp
    $(CC) -c -w -fPIC -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)svdlib.o $< $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)

./svdlibc/svdutil.o: ./svdlibc/svdutil.cpp
    $(CC) -c -w -fPIC -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)svdutil.o $< $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)  

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c  -fPIC -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)$@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)

compile_lib: Native.o Repository.o ArrayUtilTest.o FeatureToGene.o javaAnnotationItemWrapper.o javaAnnotationRetrieverWrapper.o javaDecompositionResponseWrapper.o javaPredictionResponseWrapper.o JavaRelationshipItemWrapper.o javaRelationshipRetrieverWrapper.o JavaRequestWrapper.o javaSimilarityRetrieverWrapper.o javaValidationResponseWrapper.o ./svdlibc/las2.o ./svdlibc/svdlib.o ./svdlibc/svdutil.o StopWatchUtil.o
    g++ -shared -lboost_thread  -lgomp -Wl,-soname,biocpp.so.1 -o biocpp.so.1.0 $(OUTPUT_DIR)*.o
```

Comment: Can you post the way your library is built?

Comment: @fge I did. I posted the makefile. If useful, with that makefile (with different version of AMD ACML libraries) I can compile and correctly link on 32 bit system.

Comment: Move `$(OUTPUT_DIR)*.o` to the beginning of the command line, before the libraries.

Comment: @n.m. It worked!!Thank you very very much. If you want to write an answer, maybe explaining why I need to do that, I will accept it for sure.

Comment: Please check whether you have a shared library version of `libboost_thread` installed. I can only explain this if you *don't* have `libboost_thread.so` but only `libboost_thread.a`.

Comment: @n.m. Actually I have a `libbost_thread.so` in my `/usr/lib` directory; it's a link to `libboost_thread.so.1.50.0`

Comment: I cannot reproduce or explain it with shared libraries. Perhaps you have a wrong architecture shared lib installed.